# Inserting an ignored commit between two commits

Tags: git, rebase

I have a clone of a public git repository.  Simplified, the commits (A-D) look like this:

```
   +->D
   |
A->B->C
```

Commits A and B are already in the public repo.  I added commit C to the clone that includes significant coding standard changes as well as significant feature changes.  I later decided that I wanted to add a commit D to the clone that corrects only the coding standard issues in commit B.

I'd like to reorder commit C to come after commit D, so that things look like this:

```
A->B->D->C
```

Because I've already made the coding standard changes in both commits, I'd like to tell git to accept commit C as-is with no merging.  I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.  Can anyone suggest the right approach?

I had thought that git-rebase with a merge strategy our "ours" would do the trick, but am not having luck with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout C
git reset --soft D
git commit
```

should be sufficient. `git reset --soft` merely resets what git thinks the "current" commit is, without actually making any changes whatsoever. So your index and worktree will still be *exactly* how they were in `C`, and you can commit that without needing to make any further changes.

Note that nothing in these commands will cause any sort of merge or automatic conflict resolution to take place. This means that *if* there is any part of `D` that *isn't* already part of `C`, this will cause those changes of `D` to be effectively reverted. You've stated that that's not the case, that `D` merely contains bits of `C`, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: hey @hvd, I might be wrong but you can't see D from C, if we're looking at the first diagram.

Comment: @bitoiu You're right that `D` is not an ancestor of `C`, but that isn't a problem. `git reset` doesn't care whether the specified commit is an ancestor, descendent, or completely unrelated to the current HEAD.

Comment: oh, I've learned a new thing. Very useful indeed, it just stages the changes of whatever commit you point it to. Just for that up-voted. I've always used --soft in the context of cleaning up local commits by reseting all changes to a previous point in "time"...

Answer (score 1):

I use SourceTree as the GUI for GIT
Assuming commit C is the master branch

1. Checkout commit D as "temp"
2. Select all the files in commit C, right click and "reset to commit"
3. Uncommitted changes should now show your feature changes
4. Commit your changes as E
5. Delete "master" branch
6. Checkout "temp" branch as "master"

You get the A->B->D->E, where E is C without the changes in D.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is as simple as:

```
git checkout D
git cherry-pick <commitIDofC>
```

Resolve any missing conflicts. The commit contents won't be exactly the same because they just can't be, the history at `B` and the history after `B->D` can't be the same so if you touch the same areas of the code they can't be the same.

Please try this out and let me know.

Cheers.